# How to programmatically setting style attribute in a web view …

Tags: android, android-emulator

My problem is that my web view is not properly displayed in the emulator..is there is a option display it in proper order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, a webview is simply a "port" to view webpages or roll your own browser. Generally speaking, if "things" aren't displayed correctly, webview is usually not to blame. That said, have you verified this problem on a device?